# Firebase and Godaddy: Hosting redirection to www doesn't work for https

Tags: web-hosting, https, security, godaddy, firebase

I have a website whose domain name is `example.com` from `GoDaddy` and my SSL certificate and hosting is on `firebase`.

Currently `www.example.com` forwards properly to `https://www.example.com` but `https://example.com` shows a security error on all browsers. I am trying to set it up so that `https://example.com` or `example.com` forwards to `https://www.example.com`

I added a domain forwarding to redirect it to `https://www.example.com`.

[image: GoDaddy domain forwarding]

My firebase settings are as follows:

[image: Firebase settings]

Firebase is successfully connected to the `www` version of my site but the connection to the non-www version never happens even though I already have the settings on my goDaddy as visible below:

[image: Firebase A records on GoDaddy]

And CNAME setting to connect GoDaddy to Firebase:

[image: Godaddy firebase cname]

How can I make `https://example.com` to forward to `https://www.example.com`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that GoDaddy doesn't support redirects from HTTPS. But the good news is that Firebase supports this natively and automatically.

The solution is instead of using GoDaddy for your bare domain, use Firebase. The detailed instructions can be found here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain

In essence, you will need to go to the "connect domain" section of Firebase Hosting to find the Firebase IP addresses, then go to GoDaddy and change your `A` records to point to these Firebase IPs.